# Cross table query for showing comments and thread name while both values in different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one for comments and one for the thread. They are both connected with the `thread_id` which checks what comments belong to what thread. Now I got a profile page and I want to show the comments posted by the user (which already works) and to what thread(column title) each comment belongs to. I am a beginner with cross table queries and I was wondering how I could accomplish this. Here is my code for showing the comments posted by the user:

```
$sql_result4 = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE username = '".$profileusername."'");
while($postcomments = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result4)){
        echo"<a  href='thread.php?thread_id={$postcomments['comment_id']}'>{$postcomments['comment']}</a></br>";
}
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
$sql_result4 = $mysqli2->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE username = '".$profileusername."'");
$sql_result5 = $mysqli2->query("")
while($postthread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result5){
    while($postcomments = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result4)){
        echo"<a  href='thread.php?thread_id={$postcomments['comment_id']}'>{$postcomments['comment']}</a></br>";
    }
}
```

but I have no idea what to use for `$sql_result5`

What should I put as `$sql_result5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just 1 query and use left join.

```
SELECT c.*, t.* FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN threads t ON t.id = c.thread_id
WHERE c.username = 'username'
```

Now you have all data in 1 result.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb but I dont know what's with all the c's etc.

Comment: c is just an alias (the same with t) so c.* is the same as comments.*

Comment: So how would it normally look like? without the aliases?

Comment: @Loko - It would look like: `SELECT comments.*, threads.* FROM comments  LEFT JOIN threads ON threads.id = comments.thread_id
WHERE username = 'username'`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Warning mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: @Loko What is the SQL error? Try the query directly in mysql instead. Also try the query with the aliases it is correct too, does it have the same problem.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Yup still got the error when putting it in directly

Comment: @Loko - So what is the error when you tried it directly, I want the SQL error.

Comment: @Loko You have to rename the columns and tables according to your real names.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I did this with different column and tablenames, but basically, advertentie=thread, bod=comment and advertentie_id=thread_id   - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN advertenties ON advertenties.id = bod.advertentie_id WHERE username = ' at line 1

Comment: @MahmoudGamal This is my query: SELECT bod.*, advertenties.* LEFT JOIN advertenties ON advertenties.id = bod.advertentie_id WHERE username = 'username' FROM bod

Comment: @Loko use this  `SELECT bod.*, advertenties.* FROM bod LEFT JOIN advertenties ON advertenties.id = bod.advertentie_id WHERE username = 'username'`

Comment: @Loko - Aha, this is not a valid syntax, I added a comment for tttpapi about that and he updated his answer, the `LEFT JOIN` should be after `FROM` and before `where` like this: `SELECT bod.*, advertenties.* FROM bod LEFT JOIN advertenties ON advertenties.id = bod.advertentie_id WHERE username = 'username'`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Column 'username' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @Loko - aha, if the column `username` come from `bed` write it `bed.username` if it comes from the `advertenties ` table write it `advertenties.bed`.